# compile and execute c program with argument

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I am new in C program and linux, how can we compile and run this program?

I have tried `gcc example.c` then `./a.out` but it gives an error like `input file cannot be opened` ( I have written this error in the read method)

```
// example.c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* input = argv[1];
    read(input);

    char* output = argv[2];
    write(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you managed to run this, then the compilation was successful. Please add more info about read and write methods. Also, you need to pass two arguments on the command line: `./a.out FILE1 FILE2`.

Comment: You really should compile with `gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -g example.c -o myprog`, improve your code till you get no more warnings, then run `./myprog` and learn to use the `gdb` debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program isn't going to work very well - you're not providing enough arguments to `read` and `write`, for example (assuming you mean to be calling POSIX `read(2)` and `write(2)`, that is).

To answer your actual question, the problem appears to be that you're not providing any arguments.  You need to run it something like:

```
./a.out FILE1 FILE2
```

replacing `FILE1` with the name of your input file and `FILE2` with the name of your output file.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `read()` and `write()` both take 3 arguments(only one given).

Secondly it should be used like this:

```
int ifilehandle = open(argc[1],O_RDONLY,S_IREAD);
int ofilehandle = open(argc[2],O_WRONLY,S_IWRITE);
char buffer[32767];
read(ifilehandle,&buffer,32766);
write(ofilehandle,&buffer,32766);
close(ifilehandle);
close(ofilehandle);
```

Thirdly, a.out should be invoked like this:

```
./a.out filename1.extension filename2.extension
```

Comment: +1 - you're absolutely correct.  I just wasn't sure "read()" and "write()" were necessarily the best APIs for the OP.  ADDITIONAL NOTE: if the OP uses "read()" or "write()", he should also `#include <unistd.h>`.  See [man read](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read)

Comment: I would use a power-of-two sized buffer (e.g. 16384), and read it in full.